# Plotting a 2 dimensional array of y coordinates against the array index

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a 2 dimensional array that contains the y coordinates of many particles at each time step.

For example

```
[[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
 [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
 [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5]]
```

I would like to plot this against the index of the row. For example the 1.1 value should be plotted with coordinates (0,1.1).

I have currently unwound the arrays to make a long list of x and y coordinates, but feel there must be a better solution to this.

In the code below particles is and n by N array that contains all the y coordinates.

```
particlesplotx = np.zeros(n*N)
particlesploty = np.zeros(n*N)

for t in range(0, N):
    for i in range(0, n):
        particlesplotx[t*n + i] = t
        particlesploty[t*n + i] = particles[i,t]

plt.scatter(particlesplotx, particlesploty)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is wrong with the way you are doing it? What would make the solution "better" in your mind? Are you trying to make it go faster? Fewer lines of code?

Comment: Generally both. In terms of fewer lines of code, I was thinking there must be a way of setting the arguments for plt.scatter() that allows this whole section to be achieved in one line. This in turn would be faster than the current solution as I would not need to loop through the array twice.

Comment: `plt.plot(np.array(ys).T)`?